# How to modify a Login System in msqli query to PDO?

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo, prepared-statement

```
session_start();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){ 

  $email  = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['email']);
  $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");

  if( $result->num_rows == 0 ){
   // User doesn't exist
    $_SESSION['message'] = "User with that email doesn't exist!";
    header("location: error-login.php");

  } else{ // User exists

      $user = $result->fetch_assoc();

      if( password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['password'])){

        $_SESSION['email'] = $user['email'];
        $_SESSION['first_name'] = $user['first_name'];
        $_SESSION['last_name'] = $user['last_name'];
        $_SESSION['active'] = $user['active'];


        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;

        header("location: riscar.php");

      } else {
          $_SESSION['message'] = "You have entered wrong password, try again!";
          header("location: error-login.php");
        }      
    }  
}
```

I need to modify this code above to PDO. I tried to make some changes:

```
 define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
 define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
 define('DB_PASSWORD', null);
 define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

 define('DB_DATABASE', 'publicacoes');

 $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOSTNAME . ';dbname=' . DB_DATABASE . ';charset=' . DB_CHARSET . ';', DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

 $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
 $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

session_start();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){ 

  $email = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email"); ###
  $result->execute([':email' => $_POST['email']]); ###

  if( $result->num_rows == 0 ){
   // User doesn't exist
    $_SESSION['message'] = "User with that email doesn't exist!";
    header("location: error-login.php");

  } else{ // User exists

      $user = $result->fetch_assoc();

      if( password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['password'])){

        $_SESSION['email'] = $user['email'];
        $_SESSION['first_name'] = $user['first_name'];
        $_SESSION['last_name'] = $user['last_name'];
        $_SESSION['active'] = $user['active'];


        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;

        header("location: riscar.php");

      } else {

          $_SESSION['message'] = "You have entered wrong password, try again!";
          header("location: error-login.php");

        }      
    }  
}
```

But it's not working, I got the errors:

1 - `Undefined variable: result`.
2 - `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on null`.

It gets the same error if i change &result to $email.

What's wrong with the code? I'm not familiar with `MYSQLi`. I'm thinking that maybe i need to change all the code on this login system. I need to modify it to `PDO`.

Comment: If you have to change one, you have to change all. There's a lot of differences between the two APIs. Look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to see how to get started with PDO.

Comment: Why do you execute `$result` and not `$email` (`$email = $conn->prepare(...`)?

Comment: @AlonEitan It's not working anyway

Comment: You should also check for [PDO errors](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) when things don't work, to get an error message and a direction of what's wrong beyond "it doesn't work".

Comment: Well first you need to change the Connection. `mysqli_` and `PDO` are very different. You shoudl start by reading the [PDO Manual pages](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Are you using `mysqli` and `PDO` or everything is going to be `PDO`? If all PDO can you update the question showing the real usage, not the historical?

Comment: @user3783243 No, The login system is only in `mysqli` i need to modify it to to `PDO`.

Comment: You said `I tried to change only these two lines` how did you do that if not using PDO? What is `$conn`?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I already have a connection in PDO, and i put it on the `prepared statement` that i showed on the end of the question.

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: So do you have a `MYSQLI_` connection AND a PDO connection or just PDO

Comment: @user3783243 `$conn` is my connection, please check my question again, i edited.

Comment: Okay, so in that case look back at @AlonEitan comment. `$result` is undefined. `$email` is your prepared statement, execute that. `$email->execute([':email' => $_POST['email']]);`

Comment: @user3783243 It get the same error...

Comment: `Undefined variable: email` or what error?

Comment: @RiggsFolly This login system have a `MYSQLI_ ` connection. But i need to change it to `PDO`. This `PDO` connection is the one that i created trying to modify the login system.

Comment: @user3783243 It's on my question. Please check the end of the question.

Comment: There are 2 errors there, `undefined variable` doesn't make sense, but perhaps it is from earlier in the code? Can you show the full PDO execution code? Also line numbers with the errors would be helpful.

Comment: @user3783243 Please check my question, i edited.

Comment: The error is exactly what I and AlonEitan said already. `$result` is not defined, since it is NULL it has no `execute` method. Use `$email as already stated, and shown (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429669/how-to-modify-a-login-system-in-msqli-query-to-pdo?noredirect=1#comment91803365_52429669)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you don need to `escape_string` with `pdo` prepared statement.

Secondly, you should change your database connection compatible with `pdo` along with the `pdo` attributes `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` &  `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` so that you can at least catch pdo errors and exceptions. You can add other error handling attributes too in your connection statement. See http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php for more details.

```
$DATABASESERVER = "YOUR_DATABASE_SERVER_NAME";
$DATABASENAME =  "YOUR_DATABASE_NAME";
$DATABASEUSERNAMNE = "YOUR_DATABASE_USERNAME";
$DATABASEPASSWORD = "YOUR_DATABASE_PASSWORD";


try {
$DatabaseCon = new PDO("mysql:host=$DATABASESERVER; dbname=$DATABASENAME", $DATABASEUSERNAMNE, $DATABASEPASSWORD);
$DatabaseCon->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} 
catch(PDOException $e){
echo "$DatabaseCon-> failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

and finally you can replace your code with:

```
session_start();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){ 

$email = trim($_POST['email']);

try{
$Query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=:email";
$statement = $DatabaseCon->prepare($Query);
$statement->bindValue(':email', $email);
$statement->execute();
$user = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
$RowCount = $statement->rowCount();
}
catch (PDOerrorInfo $e){
die('QuerySCD Error '.$e->getMessage());
}


  if( $RowCount == 0 ){
   // User doesn't exist
    $_SESSION['message'] = "User with that email doesn't exist!";
    header("location: error-login.php");

  } else{ // User exists


      if( password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['password'])){

        $_SESSION['email'] = $user['email'];
        $_SESSION['first_name'] = $user['first_name'];
        $_SESSION['last_name'] = $user['last_name'];
        $_SESSION['active'] = $user['active'];


        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;

        header("location: riscar.php");

      } else {
          $_SESSION['message'] = "You have entered wrong password, try again!";
          header("location: error-login.php");
        }      
    }  
}

 //close database connection
 $DatabaseCon-> = NULL;
```

However, you can also use positional place holder & bindParam method in your pdo syntax. See manual for more details.

All the best.

Comment: What is the diffrence about your PDO connection using `try` `catch` and mine PDO connection? You can just give a short answer.

Comment: try is used as of PHP 7 & 7+ it means you are asking php server to `try` and execute your query. on the other hand using `catch` you are asking the server to catch the pdo errors and exceptions. These both are elegant ways to do things.

Answer (score 0):

You're code can be written like this using my PDO wrapper class called [GrumpyPDO](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/GrumpyPDO).

```
session_start();
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){ 

    //select row of results where email is posted email
    //$db must be set prior to this
    $user = $db->row("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?", [$_POST['email']]);

    if(!empty($user)) { //user exists if $result is not empty

        //everything from here on is the same
        if(password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['password'])) {
            $_SESSION['email'] = $user['email'];
            $_SESSION['first_name'] = $user['first_name'];
            $_SESSION['last_name'] = $user['last_name'];
            $_SESSION['active'] = $user['active'];

            // This is how we'll know the user is logged in
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;

            header("location: riscar.php");
        } else {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "You have entered wrong password, try again!";
            header("location: error-login.php");
        }
    } else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "User with that email doesn't exist!";
        header("location: error-login.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's saying `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::row()`

Comment: @Susi You have to use the GrumpyPDO class for this to work. Native PDO is a little different, but GrumpyPDO streamlines it so it's easier to use. Check out other answers for Native PDO methods